# Where in memory are my variables stored in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, types

By considering that the memory is divided into four segments: data, heap, stack, and code, where do global variables, static variables, constant data types, local variables (defined and declared in functions), variables (in main function), pointers, and dynamically allocated space (using malloc and calloc) get stored in memory?

I think they would be allocated as follows:

- Global variables  ------->  data
- Static variables  ------->  data
- Constant data types ----->  code
- Local variables (declared and defined in functions)  -------->  stack
- Variables declared and defined in main function  ----->  heap
- Pointers (for example, `char *arr`, `int *arr`) ------->  heap
- Dynamically allocated space (using malloc and calloc) --------> stack

I am referring to these variables only from the C perspective.

Please correct me if I am wrong as I am new to C.

Comment: `main` is just another function.  Variables go on the stack unless `malloc`'d just like elsewhere.

Comment: Is this actually defined by C standard? I think this is more architecture dependent.

Comment: Most of the fine details are probably implementation-dependent. (I.e. there's nothing that forbids a C compiler/runtime that heap-allocates everything including "stack frames".)

Comment: static vars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-c

Comment: Note for myself: Read @Kerrek SB's answer.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You got some of these right, but whoever wrote the questions tricked you on at least one question:

- global variables -------> data (correct)
- static variables -------> data (correct)
- constant data types -----> code and/or data. Consider string literals for a situation when a constant itself would be stored in the data segment, and references to it would be embedded in the code
- local variables(declared and defined in functions) --------> stack (correct)
- variables declared and defined in `main` function -----> <strike>heap</strike> also stack (the teacher was trying to trick you)
- pointers(ex: `char *arr`, `int *arr`) -------> <strike>heap</strike> data or stack, depending on the context. C lets you declare a global or a `static` pointer, in which case the pointer itself would end up in the data segment.
- dynamically allocated space(using `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`) --------> <strike>stack</strike> heap

It is worth mentioning that "stack" is officially called "automatic storage class".

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the heap officially isn't called anything at all. Allocated memory comes from somewhere, there is no name in the standard for that "somewhere".

Comment: On some systems, (namely Linux and *BSD) there is also `alloca` which works similar to `malloc`, but does stack allocation.

Comment: I guess you understood what I meant, just to make it clear, I didn't mean to ask where `a` is stored but rather where the block of memory `a` is pointing to is.

Comment: @myradio There's no pointer in `int a[10]` or `int a[b]` declaration, they declare arrays. These arrays are placed in the automatic memory area.

Answer (score 181):

For those future visitors who may be interested in knowing about those memory segments, I am writing important points about 5 memory segments in C:

**Some heads up:**

1. Whenever a C program is executed some memory is allocated in the RAM for the program execution. This memory is used for storing the frequently executed code (binary data), program variables, etc. The below memory segments talks about the same:
2. Typically there are three types of variables:

   - Local variables (also called as automatic variables in C)
   - Global variables
   - Static variables
   - You can have global static or local static variables, but the above three are the parent types.

**5 Memory Segments in C:**

## 1. Code Segment

- The code segment, also referred as the text segment, is the area of memory which contains the frequently executed code.
- The code segment is often read-only to avoid risk of getting overridden by programming bugs like buffer-overflow, etc.
- The code segment does not contain program variables like local variable (*also called as automatic variables in C*), global variables, etc.
- Based on the C implementation, the code segment can also contain read-only string literals. For example, when you do `printf("Hello, world")` then string "Hello, world" gets created in the code/text segment. You can verify this using `size` command in Linux OS.
- [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment)

## Data Segment

The data segment is divided in the below two parts and typically lies below the heap area or in some implementations above the stack, but the data segment never lies between the heap and stack area.

### 2. Uninitialized data segment

- This segment is also known as **bss**.
- This is the portion of memory which contains:

  1. **Uninitialized global variables** ***(including pointer variables)***
  2. **Uninitialized constant global variables**.
  3. **Uninitialized local static variables**.
- Any global or static local variable which is not initialized will be stored in the uninitialized data segment
- For example: global variable `int globalVar;` or static local variable `static int localStatic;` will be stored in the uninitialized data segment.
- If you declare a global variable and initialize it as `0` or `NULL` then still it would go to uninitialized data segment or bss.
- [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)

### 3. Initialized data segment

- This segment stores:

  1. **Initialized global variables**  ***(including pointer variables)***
  2. **Initialized constant global variables**.
  3. **Initialized local static variables**.
- For example: global variable `int globalVar = 1;` or static local variable `static int localStatic = 1;` will be stored in initialized data segment.
- This segment can be **further classified into initialized read-only area and initialized read-write area**. *Initialized constant global variables will go in the initialized read-only area while variables whose values can be modified at runtime will go in the initialized read-write area*.
- ***The size of this segment is determined by the size of the values in the program's source code, and does not change at run time***.
- [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

## 4. Stack Segment

- Stack segment is used to store variables which are created inside functions (*function could be main function or user-defined function*), variable like

  1. **Local variables** of the function ***(including pointer variables)***
  2. **Arguments passed to function**
  3. **Return address**
- Variables stored in the stack will be removed as soon as the function execution finishes.
- [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation)

## 5. Heap Segment

- This segment is to support dynamic memory allocation. If the programmer wants to allocate some memory dynamically then in C it is done using the `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` methods.
- For example, when `int* prt = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)` then eight bytes will be allocated in heap and memory address of that location will be returned and stored in `ptr` variable. The `ptr` variable  will be on either the stack or data segment depending on the way it is declared/used.
- [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP)

Comment: Shouldn't that be initialized instead of uninitialized in 3. Initialized data segment.

Comment: Re *"stored in the uninitialized data segment"* (multiple instances): Do you mean *"stored uninitialized in the data segment"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean both things. *"Any global or static local variable which is not initialized will be stored in the uninitialized data segment"*

Comment: how can we have global static variable in C ?

Comment: under "some heads up", I found this point "You can have global static or local static variables, but the above three are the parent types." in which u referred to the term "global static". My point is a static variable cannot be global. i.e., if any variable has to be global then it should be accessible until the program's execution is complete. Please explain and help if I am wrong.

Comment: Modern GNU binutils `ld` separates `.rodata`, putting it in its own read-only *non-exec* segment, separate from code (I tested on GNU/Linux).  This means static constants like string literals are no longer possible candidates for Spectre / ROP gadgets because they're in non-executable pages.

Answer (score 13):

Corrected your wrong sentences

```
constant data types ----->  code //wrong
```

local constant variables -----> stack

initialized global constant variable -----> data segment

uninitialized global constant variable -----> bss

```
variables declared and defined in main function  ----->  heap //wrong
```

variables declared and defined in main function -----> stack

```
pointers(ex:char *arr,int *arr) ------->  heap //wrong

dynamically allocated space(using malloc,calloc) --------> stack //wrong
```

pointers(ex:char *arr,int *arr) -------> size of that pointer variable will be in stack.

Consider that you are allocating memory of n bytes (using `malloc` or `calloc`) dynamically and then making pointer variable to point it. Now that `n` bytes of memory are in heap and the pointer variable requries 4 bytes (if 64 bit machine 8 bytes) which will be in stack to store the starting  pointer of the `n` bytes of memory chunk.

Note : Pointer variables can point the memory of any segment.

```
int x = 10;
void func()
{
int a = 0;
int *p = &a: //Now its pointing the memory of stack
int *p2 = &x; //Now its pointing the memory of data segment
chat *name = "ashok" //Now its pointing the constant string literal 
                     //which is actually present in text segment.
char *name2 = malloc(10); //Now its pointing memory in heap
...
}
```

dynamically allocated space(using malloc,calloc) --------> heap

Comment: pointers can be in either the stack or the heap (see especially: pointers to pointers)

Comment: @airza : Now updated. ACtually I was updating that details only :)

Comment: In the following memory map, could you please point out where is stack and heap? I am not sure if this is correct question as stack and memory may be only applicable at run time.

MEMORY MAP:
"text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   7280    1688    1040   10008    2718 a.exe
"

Comment: *initialized global **constant** variable -----> data segment* Nope, this answer is wrong, the question was right about that for older linkers.  If the `.rodata` section isn't linked into the text segment (Read + eXec) along with the code like older linkers did, modern GNU `ld` defaults to linking it into its own segment which is read only and *not* executable.  If not optimized away entirely, non-zero global `const` variables certainly don't go in R+W the `.data` section or get linked into the R+W data segment.  You're right that zero-valued ones will go in `.bss` though.

Answer (score 9):

A popular desktop architecture divides a process's virtual memory in several *segments*:

- Text segment: contains the executable code. The instruction pointer takes values in this range.
- Data segment: contains global variables (i.e. objects with static linkage). Subdivided in read-only data (such as string constants) and uninitialized data ("BSS").
- Stack segment: contains the *dynamic* memory for the program, i.e. the free store ("heap") and the local stack frames for all the threads. Traditionally the C stack and C heap used to grow into the stack segment from opposite ends, but I believe that practice has been abandoned because it is too unsafe.

A C program typically puts objects with static storage duration into the data segment, dynamically allocated objects on the free store, and automatic objects on the call stack of the thread in which it lives.

On other platforms, such as old x86 real mode or on embedded devices, things can obviously be radically different.

Comment: "I believe that practice has been abandoned because it is too unsafe" - and makes it impossible to implement threads, since then you need more than one stack per program and they can't all be at the end :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I was thinking that too. But threads have existed for a long time -- I don't know if all the thread stacks also grew backwards, or if they'd grow up like the heap... anyway, nowadays everything goes in the same direction and there are guard pages.

Answer (score 7):

> *I am referring to these variables only from the C perspective.*

From the perspective of the *C language*, all that matters is extent, scope, linkage, and access; exactly how items are mapped to different memory segments is up to the individual implementation, and that will vary.  The language standard doesn't talk about memory segments *at all*.  Most modern architectures act mostly the same way; block-scope variables and function arguments will be allocated from the stack, file-scope and static variables will be allocated from a data or code segment, dynamic memory will be allocated from a heap, some constant data will be stored in read-only segments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

One thing one needs to keep in mind about the storage is the [*as-if* rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455917/918959). The compiler is not required to put a variable in a specific place - instead it can place it wherever it pleases for as long as the compiled program behaves *as if* it were run in the abstract C machine according to the rules of the abstract C machine. This applies to all storage *durations*. For example:

- a variable that is not accessed all can be eliminated completely - it has no storage... anywhere. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/dfRj90) - see how there is `42` in the generated assembly code but no sign of `404`.
- a variable with automatic storage duration that does not have its address taken need not be stored in memory at all. [An example would be a loop variable.](https://godbolt.org/z/MXIdo8)
- a variable that is `const` or effectively `const` need not be in memory. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/s_KweJ) - the compiler can prove that `foo` is effectively `const` and inlines its use into the code. `bar` has external linkage and the compiler cannot prove that it would not be changed outside the current module, hence it is not inlined.
- an object allocated with `malloc` need not reside in memory allocated from heap! [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/RZNndt) - notice how the code does not have a call to `malloc` and neither is the value 42 ever stored in memory, it is kept in a register!
- thus an object that has been allocated by `malloc` and the reference is lost without deallocating the object with `free` *need not* leak memory...
- the object allocated by `malloc` need not be within the heap *below* the program break (`sbrk(0)`) on Unixen...

Answer (score 1):

> pointers(ex:char *arr,int *arr) -------> heap

Nope, they can be on the stack or in the data segment.  They can point anywhere.

Comment: The statements about `main` and dynamically allocated variables are wrong too

Comment: Not only on the stack or data segment. Think of an pointer which points to an array of pointers. In this case the pointers in the array are stored on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

- Variables/automatic variables      ---> stack section
- Dynamically allocated variables    ---> heap section
- Initialised global variables       -> data section
- Uninitialised global variables     -> data section (bss)
- Static variables                   -> data section
- String constants                   -> text section/code section
- Functions                          -> text section/code section
- Text code                          -> text section/code section
- Registers                          -> CPU registers
- Command line inputs                -> environmental/command line section
- Environmental variables            -> environmental/command line section

Comment: What is environmental/command line section? Does they exist in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

**Linux minimal runnable examples with disassembly analysis**

Since this is an implementation detail not specified by standards, let's just have a look at what the compiler is doing on a particular implementation.

In this answer, I will either link to specific answers that do the analysis, or provide the analysis directly here, and summarize all results here.

All of those are in various Ubuntu / GCC versions, and the outcomes are likely pretty stable across versions, but if we find any variations let's specify more precise versions.

**Local variable inside a function**

Be it `main` or any other function:

```
void f(void) {
    int my_local_var;
}
```

As shown at: [What does <value optimized out> mean in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497855/what-does-value-optimized-out-mean-in-gdb/60552533#60552533)

- `-O0`: stack
- `-O3`: registers if they don't spill, stack otherwise

For motivation on why the stack exists see: [What is the function of the push / pop instructions used on registers in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass/33583134#33583134)

**Global variables and `static` function variables**

```
/* BSS */
int my_global_implicit;
int my_global_implicit_explicit_0 = 0;

/* DATA */
int my_global_implicit_explicit_1 = 1;

void f(void) {
    /* BSS */
    static int my_static_local_var_implicit;
    static int my_static_local_var_explicit_0 = 0;

    /* DATA */
    static int my_static_local_var_explicit_1 = 1;
}
```

- if initialized to `0` or not initialized (and therefore implicitly initialized to `0`): `.bss` section, see also: [Why is the .bss segment required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535250/why-is-the-bss-segment-required/36725653#36725653)
- otherwise: `.data` section

**`char *` and `char c[]`**

As shown at: [Where are static variables stored in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c/30642087#30642087)

```
void f(void) {
    /* RODATA / TEXT */
    char *a = "abc";

    /* Stack. */
    char b[] = "abc";
    char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
}
```

TODO will very large string literals also be put on the stack? Or `.data`? Or does compilation fail?

**Function arguments**

```
void f(int i, int j);
```

Must go through the relevant calling convention, e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions for X86, which specifies either specific registers or stack locations for each variable.

Then as shown at [What does <value optimized out> mean in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497855/what-does-value-optimized-out-mean-in-gdb/60552533#60552533), `-O0` then slurps everything into the stack, while `-O3` tries to use registers as much as possible.

If the function gets inlined however, they are treated just like regular locals.

**`const`**

I believe that it makes no difference because you can typecast it away.

Conversely, if the compiler is able to determine that some data is never written to, it could in theory place it in `.rodata` even if not const.

TODO analysis.

**Pointers**

They are variables (that contain addresses, which are numbers), so same as all the rest :-)

**malloc**

The question does not make much sense for `malloc`, since `malloc` is a function, and in:

```
int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`*i` is a variable that contains an address, so it falls on the above case.

As for how malloc works internally, when you call it the Linux kernel marks certain addresses as writable on its internal data structures, and when they are touched by the program initially, a fault happens and the kernel enables the page tables, which lets the access happen without segfaul: [How does x86 paging work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work)

Note however that this is basically exactly what the `exec` syscall does under the hood when you try to run an executable: it marks pages it wants to load to, and writes the program there, see also: [How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861) Except that `exec` has some extra limitations on where to load to (e.g. is the code [is not relocatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031)).

The exact syscall used for `malloc` is `mmap` in modern 2020 implementations, and in the past `brk` was used: [Does malloc() use brk() or mmap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542428/does-malloc-use-brk-or-mmap)

**Dynamic libraries**

Basically get `mmap`ed to memory: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226524/what-system-call-is-used-to-load-libraries-in-linux/462710#462710

**envinroment variables and `main`'s `argv`**

Above initial stack: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75939/where-is-the-environment-string-actual-stored TODO why not in .data?