# Get the size of heap and stack per process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory, stack-memory

I wanted to know the size of heap and stack per process in linux. Is there any way to find it?

I found out that sbrk(0) will give me the end of heap. But how can I find the start of heap to get the heap size?

Also on stack size is there any way to find the start of stack and current stack pointer address per process through any library calls or system calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, you can read `/proc/[PID]/maps` and find `[heap]` and `[stack]` entries.

But for the GLIBC heap implementations usually used on Linux, the "heap" consists of both memory obtained via `sbrk()` that shows up in the `/proc/[PID]/maps` file as `[heap]` *and* memory obtained via `mmap()` - see [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542428/malloc-does-it-use-brk-or-mmap).  So the "size" of the heap is going to be very hard to determine with certainty.

And the region labelled `[stack]` in the `maps` file is the stack for the main thread only.  Multithreaded processes will have multiple stacks, one for each thread.  And they will show up in the `maps` file as anonymous memory - maybe.  The application can control the memory used for a thread's stack via the use of `pthread_attr_setstack()` and set it to *any* memory the application might use.

Comment: Aren't there any system call to find out the stack and heap size?

Comment: @shim_mang The "system call"s used here are open(), read() and close() on /proc/PID/maps file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get in the below file. You should be root user.

```
     /proc/<pid>/maps
```