# What syscall does malloc use?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

I am studying memory management and have a question about how malloc works. 
The [malloc man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) states that:

> Normally, `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
>   size of the heap as required, using `sbrk(2)`.  When allocating blocks
>   of memory larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()`
>   implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>   using `mmap(2)`.  `MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128 kB by default, but is
>   adjustable using `mallopt(3)`.

To verify it, I did an experiment with a piece of code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    int *p = malloc(size);

    if(p)
    {
        printf("allocated %d bytes at addr: %p \n", size, p);
        free(p);
    }
    else
    {
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I traced this program with [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to see what syscall was used. Here is the result:

[image: strace result]

Why in this example did malloc call mmap instead of brk?

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542428/does-malloc-use-brk-or-mmap

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows a call to `brk` and not to `mmap` (though it's not certain that your `malloc` caused it, since `malloc` allocates in chunks and parcels out without syscalls). Are you confused by the `mmap` calls in the process initialization? Just do e.g. `printf("Hello World\n")` to see when initialization ends and your `main` starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All those `mmap()` calls are part of your program's startup when it's loading shared libraries. It's standard stuff you'll see when you `strace` most programs.

The real action is in the last few lines:

- Two calls to `brk()` coming from `malloc()`.
- An `fstat()` and a `write()` call coming from `printf()`.

You can add a printout to the top of `main()` to see when your code actually starts running.

<sup>(It's important to call the `write()` syscall directly instead of printing with `printf()` or `puts()`. The stdio functions call `malloc()` internally which muddles what we're trying to test.)</sup>

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    write(1, "start\n", 6);

    ...
}
```

When I do that I see the `write()` call right before the `brk(NULL)`, which I've marked below with a blank line:

```
...
mmap(0x7f1b34802000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f1b34802000
mmap(0x7f1b34808000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f1b34808000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f1b34a124c0) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1b34802000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x558c3cd9a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f1b34a33000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f1b34a13000, 128122)          = 0

write(1, "start\n", 6)                  = 6
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558c3dc58000
brk(0x558c3dc79000)                     = 0x558c3dc79000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
write(1, "allocated 10 bytes at addr: 0x55"..., 44) = 44
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 2):

Most `libc` implementations are open source. Study the source code of [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of 
[musl-libc](https://musl-libc.orrg/). Both implement `malloc` and `free`. Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Usually, they use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or sometimes [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)

Of course they try to minimize the number of system calls, at least for small memory sizes.

Comment: note that sbrk is a library function these days that calls brk system call.