# Why does malloc() call mmap() and brk() interchangeably?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new to C and heap memory, still struggling to understand dynamic memory allocation.

I traced Linux system calls and found that if I use `malloc` to request a small amount of heap memory, then `malloc` calls `brk` internally.

But if I use `malloc` to request a very large amount of heap memory, then `malloc` calls `mmap` internally.

So there must be a big difference between `brk` and `mmap`, but theoretically we should be able to use `brk` to allocate heap memory regardless of the requested size. So why does `malloc` call `mmap` when allocating a large amount of memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*so why malloc calls mmap when it comes to allocate a large size of memory?*

The short answer is *for improved efficiency* on newer implementations of Linux, and the updated memory allocation algorithms that come with them.  But keep in mind that this is a very implementation dependent topic, and the whys and wherefores would vary greatly for differing vintages and flavors of the specific Linux OS being discussed.

[Here is fairly recent write-up](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/unix/SbrkVersusMmap) regarding the low-level parts `mmap()` and `brk()` play in Linux memory allocation.  And, a not so recent, but still relevant [Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6390) article that includes some content that is very on-point for the topic here, including this:

> For very large requests, malloc() uses the mmap() system call to find
> addressable memory space. *This process helps reduce the negative
> effects of memory fragmentation* when large blocks of memory are freed
> but locked by smaller, more recently allocated blocks lying between
> them and the end of the allocated space. In this case, in fact, had
> the block been allocated with brk(), it would have remained unusable
> by the system even if the process freed it.
> (emphasis mine)

Regarding `brk()`:
[incidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768637/645128), "...*mmap() didn't exist in the early versions of Unix. `brk()` was the only way to increase the size of the data segment of the process at that time. The first version of Unix with mmap() was SunOS in the mid 80's, the first open-source version was BSD-Reno in 1990.*".  Since that time, modern implementation of memory allocation algorithms have been refactored with many improvements, greatly reducing the need for them to include using `brk()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222048/discussion-on-answer-by-ryyker-why-does-malloc-call-mmap-and-brk-interchan).

Comment: Note to anyone visiting this post and my answer in particular, I suggest that you click the chat link in the previous comment for some very good commentary, much of it centering on the topic of fragmentation.

Answer (score 7):

`mmap` (when used with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`) allocates a chunk of RAM that can be placed anywhere within the process's virtual address space, and that can be deallocated later (with `munmap`) independently of all other allocations.

`brk` changes the ending address of a single, contiguous "arena" of virtual address space: if this address is increased it allocates more memory to the arena, and if it is decreased, it deallocates the memory at the end of the arena.  Therefore, memory allocated with `brk` can only be released back to the operating system when a continuous range of addresses *at the end of the arena* is no longer needed by the process.

Using `brk` for small allocations, and `mmap` for big allocations, is a heuristic based on the assumption that small allocations are more likely to all have the same lifespan, whereas big allocations are more likely to have a lifespan that isn't correlated with any other allocations' lifespan.  So, big allocations use the system primitive that lets them be deallocated independently from anything else, and small allocations use the primitive that doesn't.

This heuristic is not very reliable.  The current generation of `malloc` implementations, if I remember correctly, has given up altogether on `brk` and uses `mmap` for everything.  The `malloc` implementation I suspect you are looking at (the one in the GNU C Library, based on your tags) is very old and mainly continues to be used because nobody is brave enough to take the risk of swapping it out for something newer that will *probably* but not *certainly* be better.

Comment: `brk` vs `mmap` has nothing to do with life times. It's just that the fragmentation for any possible implementation of `brk` can become arbitrarily bad if the allocation size isn't bounded (different strategies have different worst case scenarios). `mmap` is still only used when the allocation is big enough to justify giving it whole pages at once. `brk` hasn't been "removed", just effectively been inlined and made more sophisticated.

Comment: @Ext3h: Exactly: the assumption is that when small allocations are freed, they can be placed on the free list in user-space to make future allocations fast.  It's fine if there's no way to hand them back to the OS.  (The assumption breaks down if a program allocated many megabytes of small objects, and then freed them all, except for a few small allocations at the end, leaving a bunch of dirty data.)

Answer (score 2):

Reducing fragmentation is commonly given as the reason why `mmap` is used for large allocations; see [ryyker’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029494/4500798) for details. But I think that’s not the real benefit nowadays; in practice there’s still fragmentation even with `mmap`, just in a larger pool (the virtual address space, rather than the heap).

The big advantage of `mmap` is discardability.

When allocating memory with `sbrk`, if the memory is actually used (so that the kernel maps physical memory at some point), and then freed, the kernel itself can’t know about that, unless the allocator also reduces the program break (which it can’t if the freed block isn’t the topmost previously-used block under the program break). The result is that the contents of that physical memory become “precious” as far as the kernel is concerned; if it ever needs to re-purpose that physical memory, it then has to ensure that it doesn’t lose its contents. So it might end up swapping pages out (which is expensive) even though the owning process no longer cares about them.

When allocating memory with `mmap`, freeing the memory doesn’t just return the block to a pool somewhere; the corresponding virtual memory allocation is returned to the kernel, and that tells the kernel that any corresponding physical memory, dirty or otherwise, is no longer needed. The kernel can then re-purpose that physical memory without worrying about its contents.

Comment: why the kernel doesn't get notified  when allocating memory with `sbrk` has been freed? when call `free(ptr)`, we pass the staring virtual address of the block, the kernel should be aware that just like the block is allocated by using `mmap`?

Comment: Because freeing a block allocated in the heap (under the program break) doesn’t involve the kernel at all, unless the program break is also reduced. In the general case, the kernel isn’t aware of what the allocator is doing.

Answer (score 1):

`brk()` is a traditional way of allocating memory in UNIX -- it just expands the data area by a given amount. `mmap()` allows you to allocate independent regions of memory without being restricted to a single contiguous chunk of virtual address space.

`malloc()` uses the data space for "small" allocations and `mmap()` for "big" ones, for a number of reasons, including reducing memory fragmentation. It's just an implementation detail you shouldn't have to worry about.

Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542428/does-malloc-use-brk-or-mmap) also.

Answer (score 0):

the key part of the reason I think, which I copied from the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222048/discussion-on-answer-by-ryyker-why-does-malloc-call-mmap-and-brk-interchan) said by Peter

> free() is a user-space function, not a system call. It either hands them back to the OS with munmap or brk, or keeps them dirty in user-space. If it doesn't make a system call, the OS must preserve the contents of those pages as part of the process state.

So when you use brk to increase your memory adress, when return back, you have to use the brk a negtive value, so brk only can return the most recently memory block you allocated, when you call malloc(huge), malloc(small), free(huge). the huge cannot be returned back to system, you can only maintain a list of fragmentation for this process, so the huge is actually hold by this process. this is the drawback of brk.

but the mmap and munmap can avoid this.

Answer (score -2):

I want to emphasize another view point.

malloc is system function that allocate memory.

You do not really need to debug it, because in some implementations, it might give you memory from static "arena" (e.g. static char array).

In some other implementations it may just return null pointer.

If you want to see what mallow really do, I suggest you look at
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html

Linux gcc malloc is based on this.

You can take a look at jemalloc too. It basically uses same brk and mmap, but organizes the data differently and usually is "better".

Happy researching.

Comment: This is hardly a useful answer to a question about the design choices made by glibc malloc.  Someone had to design and write glibc's malloc.

Comment: I think this answer present another important point of view. The author of the question seems doing exactly the same research I did 4-5 years ago. I am sure my answer is very useful for him, even it will collect some downvotes.