# Difference between allocating large number of memory in a single go and declaring little memory step by step

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Recently I was learning about the difference between **Array** and **Linked-Lists**. There I found that:

- In Array memory is allocated in **compile-time**. In the case of Linked-List memory is allocated during the **execution on runtime** dynamically.

Then I saw a comparison [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyG9S9nAlUM&ab_channel=Computerphile) between array and linked-list made by **Computerphile**
There I learned about some key differences in the runtime of an array and linked-list in machines having a cache memory and not having it.

---

Now I was wondering that, 
In the case of allocating a large number of data (e.g: 10^7 integers) is there any difference between:

- I allocate 10^7 blocks in the memory at the beginning of the program (e.g: `int ar[10^7];` ~ Declaring array in C)
- I allocate 10^7 blocks one by one while taking input dynamically (e.g: implementing linked-list)

> If there are differences indeed, how significant is that?

Comment: The difference is memory fragmentation.

Comment: Arrays and Linked list  can be allocated at run time using `malloc`.

Comment: @Barmar: And memory use; the array has no real overhead, the linked list has per-node overhead for forward (and possibly reverse) pointers, and the allocator itself adds overhead and (often) alignment losses that increase the actual memory used. For a simple array vs. linked list of `int`s on a 64 bit machine, the memory required for the linked list is probably at least 4x the memory used by an array with the same contents, even if it's just a singly-linked list, not doubly-linked.

Comment: I was wondering about is there any **runtime** difference in allocating ` at the beginning (memory fragmentation) ` vs ` in runtime one by one (using malloc)`

Comment: Each call to `malloc()` and family make a request to the operating system, which in turn provisions your process with a contiguous block of memory at some address.  Subsequent calls are not guaranteed to give you addresses anywhere close the prior calls.  If you need a large block of contiguous memory, ask for it in one call.  There are [several good discussions on this topic in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64029219/645128).

Comment: Linked lists can also be allocated just fine at compile time. Whoever taught you the distincion you believe is true was entirely wrong.