# C problems with allocation

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to read an indefinite number of digits from standard input and write them to an array, but when reading 1050 numbers, the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("\nLength = %d\n", length);

    int array[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("\nAll data are scanned\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not "dynamic memory allocation", you know that, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well the array is allocated at run-time, so it's in a way "dynamic"... :)

Comment: @Bobikwerty Arrays, compile-time or variable-length arrays (like the one you have created), are usually allocated and created on the *stack*. The stack is a limited resource, on Windows it's only one single MiB by default, on e.g. Linux 8 MiB. Now take your size (the number of elements) and multiply with the size of `int` (`sizeof(int)`, usually 4 bytes) and you'll get the number of bytes needed. Will it fit?

Comment: Also, if you want (theoretically) "infinite" values you need to use `malloc` and `realloc` to create and recreate your array as numbers are added. But note the "theoretically" bit, because no computer in history have infinite memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because your array is being allocated on the stack, you're causing a stack overflow which crashes your program. You can use `malloc()` to allocate memory [on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68567989/where-does-malloc-allocate-memory-is-it-the-data-section-or-the-heap-section/68568074#68568074). As an alternative, you can make it static.

Consider reading [this](https://cs61.seas.harvard.edu/site/2022/Datarep/#Segments). It is good reading for understanding data segments.