# Double pointers, dynamic allocation, and using pointer arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

So I have narrowed the code to exactly what I need help with. Sorry for the wall of text and scrappy code before.

```c
// Headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Function Protype
void test_function(int **ptr2);

// Main Function
int main(void) {
    int *ptr1;
    int i = 0; // Counter

    test_function(&ptr1); // Calling function

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", ptr[i]); // Should print numbers from 0-9
    }

    return 0;
}

// Custom Function
void test_function(int **ptr2) {
    // Variables
    int i = 0; // Counter
    int j = 0; // Dynamic allocator

    *ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * j); // Allocates 10 slots of size int

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        *ptr2[i] = i; // <----- This line gives a segmentation fault error
    }

    return;
}
```

So basically, this program should iterate through an array using malloc to assign a dynamic size of j, input the numbers 0-9 and display the 0-9 to the user. However the line in the function `test_function` that is commented is giving me a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you which line of code is triggering the seg fault and this is info you should share with us. Also, try to make your question concise: the code, what it is supposed to do and what it is actually doing. For example, why do you show two versions of the code? What are we supposed to take from that and which one are you really asking about?

Comment: install GDB (GNU debugger) it will take you 10 mins to figure out your mistake

Comment: How are we supposed to debug this entire program? Reduce it.

Comment: The lines `spacePos = malloc(sizeof(*spacePos[j]));` and `printf("%p", spacePos[j]);` should be removed. Also `*spacePos[j]` should be `(*spacePos)[j]`

Comment: also you only `malloc` space for one `int` but then you index multiple places into that space

Comment: in the updated code, change `*ptr2[i]` to `(*ptr2)[i]`

Comment: You can remove the struck-out lines from your post, anyone who wants to see the old revisions can view the edit history

Comment: @M.M Awesome! That seemed to have fixed it. Thanks man. Is that just correct pointer array syntax? Thanks again man, really appreciate it. How do I marked this as solved?

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `*ptr2[i] = i;` should be:

```
(*ptr2)[i] = i;
```

The way you had it means `*(ptr2[i])` which is an error because `ptr2` only points to one thing.

Answer (score 0):

`int *spacePos = NULL;`

`find_spaces(name, &spaceCount, &spacePos);`

`SpacePos` is already a pointer to an `int`, and the pointer points to some space in memory where the integer is stored. this pointer address is stored in memory at address `&SpacePos` somewhere in your data segment in memory [Where in memory are my variables stored in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588767/where-in-memory-are-my-variables-stored-in-c).

when you pass the address of 'SpacePos' to a function and manipulate it, you are actually changing the pointer value stored in `SpacePos` and not what its pointing to, and a seg fault will result. (you essentially changed the memory address stored in `SpacePos`, now you are pointing to invalid memory)

[What does "dereferencing" a pointer mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean)

try `find_spaces(name, &spaceCount, spacePos);`
Hope it helps.

######################### PART 2

`void test_function(int **ptr2) {`

```
int i = 0; // Counter
int j = 10; // Dynamic allocator
*ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * j); // Allocates 10 slots of size int

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *((*ptr2)+i) = i; // <----- This line gives a segmentation fault error
}

return;
```

`}`

Comment: I think he wants to pass `&spacePos` so that the `find_spaces` function can dynamically allocate an array to store the "return values"

Comment: yes your right(my mistake) i'll leave my comment since it might be useful for the OP but dont give me any points, whats the standard convection in this case should he say `void *spacepos = NULL` and cast it at a later stage when he allocates memory, since it can be misleading?

Comment: No, `int *spacePos` is correct because it is indeed going to point to `int`

Comment: @M.M Hey sorry guys, I made my coding more concise in an edit. Can you check it out? I appreciate the time you guys have put out for this so far. I still need to learn a lot more about pointers and malloc.