# Global and Local Scope Variables ( Why is the 2nd printout 28 here? )

Tags: c, variables, scope, global, local

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 3, j = 10;

int crypt(int j)
{
  return (i = i+j);
}

void decrypt(int x, int i)
{
  j += crypt(i);
}

int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  i = crypt(5);
  decrypt(i, j);
  printf("|%d %d|", i, j);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why does it printout |8 28|.

The "8" part, I understand that at

i = crypt(5) -> j is now 5 in this function -> i = i + j -> There's no i therefore it uses the global variable i = 3 -> i = 3 + 5 -> returns i = 8

So the i in the main function becomes 8.

But what about the next printout? Why is it 28 instead of 23?

The way I read it was like this

decrypt(i, j) -> decrypt(8, 10) -> x is now 8 and i is now 10 in this function -> j += crypt(i) -> j += crypt(10) -> j in this function is now 10.

return ( i = i + j ), there's no i in this function so i = 3 + 10... returns 13?

So then j += 13 is 23?

Which part of the step did I mess up? I've been reading local / global scope online and I still don't quite get where did I go wrong... Feels like I'm messing up my value for i somewhere.

PS: I apologize for the poor formatting, not quite sure how else can I put it cleanly.

Comment: try compiling with `-Wshadow`, if you are using gcc.

Comment: You forget the assignment in `i = i + j`. In the second call to `crypt` the value of the global `i` is no longer `3`.

Comment: `return ( i = i + j ), there's no i in this function so i = 3 + 10... returns 13?` You have already changed the global `i` to `8` in the previous call to crypt. So `i` is 8 now

Comment: And all that explains why playing with globals and partially hiding them in locals is so dangerous...

Comment: As @SergeBallesta said, this is a bad practice. Did you compiler not warn you that the local variables were hiding the globals? If not, look into enabling compiler warnings. They will save you a lot of grief in future.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I'll look into changing my compiler settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

> return ( i = i + j ), there's no i in this function so i = 3 + 10... returns 13?

No, `i` is not 3 anymore. It was changed to 8 previously, i.e. here `return (i = i+j);` due to the first call of `crypt`

When you write:

> So the i in the main function becomes 8.

it's correct but the global `i` was changed as well.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I see where I went wrong. I completely forgot about the ( i = i+j) affecting the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have here a global i and j, and a local i var. In the main when ever you refer to i, it first checks your current scope - so any changes there will be made on your local i, and the global i will not change. if you ask a function out side of main to do something with i var, it checks its own scope first, and then checks for global i var. in this case the changes that will be made are on the global i.

So.. first time-

local i is set in main and then receives the value of i = crypt(5); another thing is that in this function you also assign the 8 value to the global i-> (i = i+j), before returning the 8 value to the local i.

second function:

decrypt(i, j); here you send the local i(= 8) and global j(=10) to the function, in it you have:

j += crypt(i);
which gives you j= j+((global) i = 8 + 10): 10+8+10. and also set your global i to 18.

Answer (score 0):

> **Global variables** are declared outside any function, and they can be
>   accessed (used) on any function in the program. **Local variables** are
>   declared inside a funcion, and can be used only inside that function.
>   It is possible to have local variables with the same name in different
>   functions.

At the first call of function **crypt(5);** you have modified the global variable value to,

> i = i+j ---->  i = 3+5 ----> i=8

And when **decrypt()** function is called, **i=8** 
Because of i is 8 **j prints 28** after additon which is a global variable .

[You can see how memory is allocated in **C**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588767/where-in-memory-are-my-variables-stored-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following version of the code, where variables have been renamed to avoid any confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int iGlobal = 3, jGlobal = 10;

int crypt(int jParam)
{
  return (iGlobal = iGlobal+jParam);
}

void decrypt(int xUnused, int iParam)
{
  jGlobal += crypt(iParam);
}

int main(void)
{
  int iLocal = 0;
  iLocal = crypt(5);
  decrypt(iLocal, jGlobal);
  printf("|%d %d|", iLocal, jGlobal);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, it should be relatively easy to explain what happens when the code is executed:

1. In `main()`, `iLocal` is zet to 0
2. `main` calls `crypt(5)`
3. `crypt` evaluates `iGlobal+jParam`, i.e. 3+5, and assigns the result to `iGlobal`, i.e. `iGlobal` is 8
4. `crypt` returns 8
5. `main` assigns the return value of 8 to `iLocal`
6. `main` calls `decrypt(8,10)`
7. `decrypt` calls `crypt(10)`
8. `crypt` evaluates `iGlobal+jParam`, i.e. 8+10, and assigns the result to `iGlobal`, i.e. `iGlobal` is 18
9. `crypt` returns 18
10. `decrypt` adds the return value of 18 to `jGlobal`, i.e. `jGlobal` is 28
11. `printf` prints the values of `iLocal`, 8, and `jGlobal`, 28

The complicated part, if any, is knowing when the global variables are replaced (a.k.a. hidden, or shadowed) by their local counterparts, the answer being "whenever possible".