# why OS create the virtual memory for running process

Tags: c, memory, process, stack, virtual

when a program started the OS will create a `virtual memory`, which divided into `stack`, `heap`, `data`, `text` to run a process on it.I know that each segment is used for specification purpose such as `text` saves the binary code of program, `data` saves `static` and `global` variable. My question is why the OS need to create the `virtual memory` and divide it into the segments ? How about if OS just use the physical memory and the process run directly on the physical memory. I think maybe the answer is related with running many process at the same time, sharing memory between process but i am not sure. It is kind if you give me an example about the benefit of creating `virtual memory` and dividing it into the segments.

Comment: Such sections typically have different protections, for example, only 'text' is executable.

Comment: it might be helpful for you to read about "single address space" OSs.  the literature around them seems relevant for this and your last question

Answer (score 1):

In an environment with memory protection via a memory mapping unit, *all* memory is virtual (mapped via the MMU). It's possible to simply map each virtual address linearly to physical addresses, while still using the protection capabilities of the MMU, but doing that makes no sense. There are many reasons to prefer that memory not be directly mappped, such as being able to share program instructions and shared library code between instances of the same program or different programs, being able to `fork`, etc.