# Is there a difference between the locations assigned to static and dynamic variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there a limitation to the locations dynamic variables can have, and is it different for static variables?
Is there a partition in the memory of the process where dynamic variables can't be allocated and static variables can be allocated?

---

I was working with an online IDE for C and experimenting with pointers when I noticed dynamically allocated variables appeared to have a shorter direction when printing them.
(Example)

- Static variable pointer: 0x7ffc49f6fbe4
- Dynamic variable pointer: 0x15512a0

At first, this made me think that the pointers of dynamic variables had a smaller size than the ones of static variables.
I tried a few things to know if this was the case: first I tried looking at the pointers of various types to know if this only applied to dynamic variables.
Then, I tried sizeof() with dynamic and static variable pointers:

```
  int a;
  int *b=malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("%lu\n%lu",sizeof(&a),sizeof(b));
```

Both returned 8 bytes.  I counted the bytes in the printed hexadecimal values. Static variables had 16 hex digits = 8 bytes, while the dynamic variables had 7 hex digits = 4 bytes. This halving of the byte gave me another idea: maybe static and dynamic directions have different sections of the memory where they can be allocated, so when I print the direction of a dynamic pointer it doesn't bother to give me the whole direction and just prints the sections a dynamic pointer can occupy. This was reinforced when I added 1 to the directions and the last hex was the one to change in both pointers. If I added enough to force the print to show another digit it also showed the new one:

```
  int a, *b;
  int *c=malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("%p\n%p\n%p",&b,c,c+67108864);
```

Shows:

```
0x7fffc15b5920
0x211e2a0
0x1211e2a0
```

I tried looking for this question but couldn't find it, so I am making it.

Comment: To display the full address, try `%8p` on a 32bit compiler, or `%16p` on a 64bit compiler. (Yes, the addresses of static `global` data and `heap` data do not have to be near one-another.) You may even be seeing addresses of a third type: _stack variables_... Not enough code to determine...

Comment: Leading zero's can be omitted. `when I added 1 to the directions and the last hex was the one to change` Of course. thats how math works. `If I added enough to force the print to show another digit it also showed the new one` Again, just how math works. Leading zeros can be ommited, a leading one can not.

Comment: Static variables are assigned their address when the program starts.  Dynamically allocated variables are allocated on demand and typically at an address higher than the static variables (though your data may be contradicting that assertion). But it is all largely immaterial to a program — you don't really need to worry about where the variables are allocated, only that they are allocated and that you don't access outside the bounds of the variables. Unless you're programming in odd MS-DOS environments, all pointers to objects (not functions) will be the same size — for you, always 64-bits.

Comment: Any limitation is implementation-specific. Your system has a 64 bit virtual address space, it's up to your OS to decide how it allocates memory to your program. You should not assume or depend on any specific limitations.

Comment: `"%p"` is sufficient.  A leading width is not needed.

Comment: It is not at all unusual for stack and heap to start out at different ends of the memory. But guess what happens when they both grow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing particularly special about the locations of various objects. Where they are is simply a matter of the need to organize memory to support various features. In the course of doing that, arbitrary choices are made, and other choices could be possible.

There is various software involving in planning the layout of memory for a program and loading it into memory. Static objects are defined in the executable file for a program, having been put there during the compiler and linking process. The program loader reads the executable file to see how much memory it needs for those objects and plans some space for them in the virtual address space of the process being created.

Processes also have a stack, so the program loader plans some space for that. Typically, the executable file contains information on how much stack space the program wants.

When the program starts, software within in initializes the C environment, including planning space for dynamic allocations.

There are complications to this, such as needing to load additional static objects when a program calls routines in a dynamically loaded library, reserving additional space for stacks of new threads within the process. Essentially, the people who write the software that loads programs and the software that manages memory within a process have developed plans for this, so, on any particular operating system, the default layout has static objects in some portion of the address space, stack in another portion, and dynamically allocated memory in another portion.

> … another idea: maybe … when I print the direction of a dynamic pointer it doesn't bother to give me the whole direction and just prints the sections a dynamic pointer can occupy.

When you print a pointer with `%p`, complete information about it is printed. (Note that a pointer should be converted to `(void *)` when printing this way.) It is not just a portion of the address information. If the `%p` output for some pointers have more or fewer digits than others, that is just because the number of digits needed to display their values is more or fewer, the same as it is with numbers generally.

Answer (score 2):

Try compiling and running the following on your (64 bit) system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    static int a; // static
    int b; // on the stack
    int *c = malloc( sizeof *c ); // preferable syntax for dynamic ('heap') allocation
    /* Omitting verification of success */

    // Edit: added (void*) after reading @Eric's high quality answer...
    printf( "%16p\n%16p\n%16p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)&b, (void*)c );

    free( c ); // don't forget!

    return 0;
}
```

Notice the large differences in the addresses of these three types of storage.

`c` is a pointer variable on the stack. `*c` is an integer variable in heap memory.

**EDIT:**
There's yet another type of data storage: read-only storage.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    static int a; // static but MUTABLE
    int b; // on the stack
    int *c = malloc( sizeof *c ); // preferable syntax for dynamic ('heap') allocation
    /* Omitting verification of success */

    printf( "%16p\n%16p\n%16p\n", (void*)&a, (void*)&b, (void*)c );

    free( c ); // don't forget!

    char *d = "one two three"; // IMMUTABLE (read-only) string literal

    printf( "%16p\n%16p\n", (void*)d, (void*)&"one two three" ); // and again

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that there are two instances of the same string. The compiler will determine that those instances are exactly the same, use only one of them, and emit appropriate code referencing the same read-only memory location. Although it is stored *near to* the mutable static variable `a`, attempting to modify a string literal will trigger an error and terminate the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers (pun intended), I made a few tries with @Fe2O3's answer, and did this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void test(){
  int f;
  printf("\
local:   %16p\n", (void*)&f);
}

int d;
int main() {
  static int a; // static
  int b; // on the stack
  int *c = malloc( sizeof *c ); // preferable syntax for dynamic ('heap') allocation
  /* Omitting verification of success */
  const int e;
  int *g;
  int *const h;
  // Edit: added (void*) after reading @Eric's high quality answer...
  test();
  printf( "\
static:  %16p\n\
main:    %16p\n\
dynamic: %16p\n\
global:  %16p\n\
const:   %16p\n\
function:%16p\n\
pointer:      %16p\n\
const pointer:%16p", (void*)&a, (void*)&b, (void*)c, (void*)&d, (void*)&e, &test, (void*)&g, (void*)&h );

  free( c ); // don't forget!

  return 0;
}
```

It prints this:

```
local:     0x7ffcc65e5e78
static:          0x404014
main:      0x7ffcc65e5e84
dynamic:         0x9692a0
global:          0x404018
const:     0x7ffcc65e5e80
function:        0x401160
pointer:        0x7ffcc65e5e78
const pointer:  0x7ffcc65e5e70
```

It's interesting how the memory space used by the function was immediately reused by the pointer after being freed.

Edit: I found the different places where variables are stored in this answer [Where in memory are my variables stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588866/19338401)