# GDB returns <optimized out> for array values

Tags: c, linux, debugging, ubuntu, gdb

I'm trying to complete [Problem 4 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4), and I've been trying to debug my solution for quite awhile now. The bug itself isn't part of my question – I can't figure out why GDB won't show me an array value necessary to figuring out the bug.

Whenever gdb reaches this loop,

```
for (int i = numDigits; i > 0; i--) {
    numArray[i-1] = prevPalindrome % 10;
    prevPalindrome /= 10;
```

I am unable to get a value from GDB by the command `print numArray` or `print numArray[0]` or `print numArray[5]`.

GDB instead does the following:

- `print numArray` returns `$1 = <optimized out>`
- Both `print numArray[0]` and `print numArray[5]` return `value has been optimized out'

I have already scoured StackOverflow for a way to fix this. I have attempted the following, and none have worked:

- My makefile already uses `-O0` (its command is `clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    test.c  -lcs50 -lm -o test`), so I tried to use just `clang -O0 test.c  -lcs50 -lm -o test`. This did not do anything.
- I tried using `-0g`, and I got a compiler error.
- I tried making the numArray volatile. I got the code to compile, but it was still `<optimized out>`.
- I tried TUI mode [at the suggestion of @Zan-Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1354762/4176019), and it was quite cool, but I to be honest I got lost and it was still `<optimized out>`.

Is there something I am missing here? Shouldn't I just be able to print an array value?

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/jhschwartz/EUler/blob/master/test.c), with the loop in question on line 95.

Comment: Just use `numArray` in your code.

Comment: My god that is a simple solution. I feel so stupid. Should I leave the question open to get a solution to the optimization problem itself? (This would be to document it, not for me.)

Comment: Don't delete it manually, let us take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible causes I can think of:

1. You are debugging the wrong binary (i.e. you think you are debugging `-O0` binary, but are in fact debugging an `-O2` or `-O3` binary).
2. Your GDB is too old compared to your GCC, and doesn't understand newer debugging format.

To eliminate possibility of #1, add abort() before accessing `numArray`, rebuild your program, run it under GDB, and confirm that it dies with `SIGABRT`. If it does not, my guess is correct and you are debugging a different binary from the one you think you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Will just `-g` work?  Also, leave out the `O0`.  As in `clang -g -std=c99 -Wall -Werror test.c -lcs50 -lm -o test`.